# Asymptotes of a logarithmic and rational Function with absolute value.

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, limits, asymptotics, absolute-value

I'm trying to find the asymptotes of the following function:
$$f(x)=|x-1| \log\Big(\sqrt{x^2 +3x+3}-x-1\Big)$$

Its domain should be this: $D(f)=(-\infty, +\infty)$;

I proceed studying the limit on the left border:
$$\lim_{x\to\ - \ \infty} |x-1| \log\Big(\sqrt{x^2 +3x+3}-x-1\Big);$$
$$\lim_{x\to\ - \ \infty} |x-1| \log\Bigg(|x|\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}-x-1\Bigg);$$
I discuss the absolute values: $$|x-1|=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x-1 <=>x\geq1  \\ 
1-x <=>x\lt 1
\end{array}
\right. \ \text{and}\  \ |x|=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x <=>x\geq0  \\ 
-x <=>x\lt0
\end{array}
\right.; $$

So I obtain: 
$$\lim_{x\to\ - \ \infty} (1-x) \log\Bigg((-x)\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}-x-1\Bigg);$$
$$\lim_{x\to\ - \ \infty} (1-x) \log\Bigg[(-x)\Bigg(\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}+1+\frac1x\Bigg)\Bigg];$$
$$\lim_{x\to\ - \ \infty} x\Bigg(-1+\frac1x\Bigg) \Bigg[\log(-x)+\log\Bigg(\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}+1+\frac1x\Bigg)\Bigg];$$
$$->+\infty\big[+\infty + \log(2)\big]=+\infty \ ;$$
While, on the right border:
$$\lim_{x\to\ + \ \infty} (x-1) \log\Bigg(x\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}-x-1\Bigg);$$
$$\lim_{x\to\ + \ \infty} x\Bigg(1-\frac1x\Bigg) \Bigg[\log(x)+\log\Bigg(\sqrt{1 +\frac3x+\frac3{x^2}}-1-\frac1x\Bigg)\Bigg];$$
$$->+\infty\big[+\infty + \log(0)\big]=+\infty \ ;$$
But, consulting Wolfram Alpha, the right limit should be: $-\infty$.

Since my calculations are wrong, I'm not able to find obliques asymptotes.

Could someone point me out where I'm doing wrong or just give me a hint to find the correct solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help: $$\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a} = {b-a\over \sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}$$

so

$$f(x)=|x-1| \log\Big({x^2+3x+3-x^2-2x-1\over \sqrt{x^2 +3x+3}+x+1}\Big)$$
$$ = |x-1| \log\Big({x+2\over \sqrt{x^2 +3x+3}+x+1}\Big)$$

so
$$ \lim _{x\to \infty}f(x)= \lim _{x\to \infty}|x-1| \log\underbrace{\Big({x(1+2/x)\over x(\sqrt{1 +3/x+3/x^2}+1+1/x)}\Big)}_{\longrightarrow {1\over 2}}= -\infty$$
since $\log (1/2)<0$

Comment: Do you know why my solution is wrong? I think it is because I wrote log(0), which is something not acceptable to write, and so I couldn't say that it goes to $+ \infty$ since the expression does not have sense.